# honda steed vlx 400, 1994 model

Tags: honda, motorcycle

1. what is the exact valve clearance of Honda steed 400.
2. I cannot remove the battery outside. I already remove the 2 screws but still I cannot pull it out.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the spec for the VLX600 - I saw another spec for the VLX400 which was newer than yours (by over 10 years) and it was the same:

> - Intake - 0.15±0.02mm (0.006±0 . 0008 in)
> - Exhaust - 0.20±0.02mm (0.008±0 . 0008 in)

As for the battery, if you cannot pull it out, something else must be holding it in. Double check what you have taken off. Does the battery wiggle at all? According to [this source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B28GkOK3QDM-WEQteXppb0U3X2c/view) you need to:

> - Remove the right side cover.
> - Unhook the fuse box from the battery case cover.
> - Remove the battery case cover by removing the bolts.
> - Remove the left side cover.
> - Disconnect the battery negative terminal lead from the battery
>     first, then disconnect the positive terminal lead.
> - Pull the battery out of the battery case.

The same source is where I got the valve clearance.